Unperturbed eigenvector combination for degenerate case in perturbation theory
My question has arised from the previously asked question. In short: I have Hamiltonian with a perturbation such that $\hat{H} = \hat{H_0} + \lambda \hat{V}$. I know eigenvectors for the unperturbed matrix $\hat{H_0}$ and perturbed matrix $\hat{H}$ itself. But there is a difference now between my problem and previous one: I don't know what the perturbation is. I just obtain perturbed Hamiltonian, unperturbed eigevectors and fact that original eigevalue with some multiplicty $n$ is now also somehow perturbed and likely it splits on $n$ different eigenvalues.
Given this knowledge can I form a combination of unpetrturbed eigenalues such that I can estimate perturbed eigenvalues? If yes, then what is the approach of this combination forming?
